# Extracting all possible user comments for Reddit

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, reddit

I am trying to do sentiment analysis for a particular reddit link

```
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/LegendsOfRuneterra/comments/gqdwy2/patch_12_discussion_megathread/'
sub = reddit.submission(url = url)
comments = [comment.body for comment in sub.comments if hasattr(comment, "body")]  
print(comments)
```

1) The code works, but the comments look to be too few. I wonder if I am doing something wrong?
2) It also seems like there is a natural limit, something like 1000 comments? How do I extract all the data?

Comment: This code is not reproducible

Comment: Read here: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html
When you visit a Reddit submission link with a lot of comments you don't see all comments. That's also what your script sees. You need to click the see more comments link to load more comments. That's something you have to do in your code which is described in the link.

Comment: @Ahmet, I have editted the code. Sorry, there was a type; it was referencing a value somewhere else earlier in the code. Confused myself. Still, its not generating the full 2400 comments